# Order of a group given group presentation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

> Suppose that $G$ is the group generated by $a,b$ satisfying the relations $ba=a^2b, ab=b^2a$, then how can I find the cardinality of this group?

I've tried to rearrange these two relations by doing some cancellation and substitution, but nothing worked out.

Comment: What you have described in a group ***presentation***, not a group **re**presentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ab=b(ba)=ba^2b$ so $a=ba^2$, hence $ba=1$ and $b=a^{-1}$.

Putting this into $ba=a^2b$ gives us $1=a$, so $G$ is the trivial group.